# "Unexpected call to method or property access." in IE with appendChild()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

```
function fload(){
  f = document.createElement('iframe');
  f.setAttribute('id','iframe');
  f.setAttribute('src','http://www.wtsp.com/news/article/199268/8/man-falls-behind-on-payments-mortgage-company-has-home-trashed');
  f.setAttribute('frameborder','0');
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(f);
}
```

I'm trying to load an iframe after everything else loads. Above is the code. In IE9, the console shows "SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access." pointing to the line with appendChild().

Also, is it possible to load the iframe asynchronously?

Comment: You should scope `f` to that function with `var`. Also, are you certain an element with the `content` id exists at the time this code is ran?

Comment: It's working here in IE9 as shown in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GVNSf/.  I think that means that document.getElementById('content') must not be working in your actual page.  When are you calling fload.  Is it after the page has been loaded?  If you're calling it too early, then the content object may not exist yet.

Comment: The frame will load asynchronously as is.

Comment: I found out I was running IE in IE7 compatibility mode, I switched it back to default and the error stopped appearing. I added "var" just in case.

Answer (score 2):

As commentors have said, likely the element with id *content* does not exist yet. Also, you don't need to use *setAttribute*, just set the DOM properties directly:

```
function fload(){
  var f;
  var el = document.getElementById('content');

  if (el && el.appendChild) {
    f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.id = 'iframe';
    f.src = 'http://...';
    f.frameborder = '0';
    el.appendChild(f);
  }
}
```

You should not call the above function until you are confident the element exists, say after the load event or similar.